# Prove that $g(U_n)$ converges in probability to $0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-distribution

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\{U_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a collection of random variables such that $U_n\sim \text{Unif}(0,n)$ (uniform distribution) for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that if $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$  is a Borel measurable function satisfying $\lim_{x\to \infty}|g(x)|=0$, then $g(U_n)$ converges in probability to $0$.

This is an exercise that can be found in the page 47 of this [PDF](https://adembo.su.domains/stat-310c/lnotes.pdf).

---

I know that $\mathbb{P}(|g(U_n)|>\varepsilon )=n^{-1}\int _\mathbb{R} \mathbf{1}_{\{|g|>\varepsilon \}}(x)\mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}(x)dx$ for any $\varepsilon >0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, however I don't know how to continue.

---

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 3):

Given $\varepsilon>0$, there is $a>0$ such that
$$|g(x)|<\varepsilon,\qquad\text{whenever}\quad x>a$$.

It follows that
$$\{|g(U_n)|>\varepsilon\}\subset \{ U_n\leq a\}$$
Hence
$$P[|g(U_n)|>\varepsilon]\leq P[ U_n\leq a]=\frac{\min(a,n)}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$

Comment: I think that $\{0\leq U_n\leq a\}$ should be changed to $\{U_n\leq a\}$, correct? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @rfloc: In this case, it's all the same

Comment: But $U_n$ can be negative.

Comment: @rfloc: $U_n$ cannot be negative since $U_n$ is supported in $[0,n]$ being a uniform random variable over $0,n]$ and presumably $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Also $\{0\leq U_n\leq a\}=\{U_n\leq a\}$ since $\{U_n\geq0\}=\Omega$. I just kept the lower bound $0$ as I was working fast on my posting before leaving my office. If it confuses you, I will remove that from my posting, but there is no harm in it.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\vert g(x) \vert \to 0$ as $x \to \infty,$ then (with the eventual exception of a null set that does not matter when integration is concerned), there exists $n_\varepsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\vert g(x) \vert < \varepsilon$ whenever $x \geq n_\varepsilon.$ Then
$$\mathbb{P}(|g(U_n)|>\varepsilon )=n^{-1}\int_\mathbb{R} \chi_{\{|g|>\varepsilon \}}(x)\chi_{[0,n]}(x)dx \leq \\
n^{-1} \int\chi_{[0, n_\varepsilon] \cap [0, n]}(x) dx \leq \frac{n_{\varepsilon}}{n}$$
for large enough $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ As $\varepsilon$ is fixed, the latter quantity converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty,$ so $g(U_n)$ converges in probability to $0.$ I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!